# How to detect Observable async item loaded using AngularFire

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Ionic and Google's Cloud Firestore via the Angular Firestore package to load some data from my object collection in firestore.

I have the following code (cut down for this example) to load a list of schedule objects:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-schedule',
  templateUrl: 'list.html'
})
export class SchedulePage {
  itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Schedule>;
  items: Observable<Schedule[]>;
  constructor(
    public db: AngularFirestore) {
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Loading..."
    });

    loader.present().then(() => {
      this.itemsCollection = this.db.collection('userschedules');
      this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
      loader.dismiss();
    });
  }  
}
```

I then have a template with the following:

```
<ion-item class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
    ...
</ion-item>
```

And that all works nicely.

However, I want to be able to make a second call as each item is loaded to go and retrieve a status for each item shown in the list from another API I have constructed and feed the result from that call into a visual indicator on the item in the list.

I'm new to Observables and not sure where I could hook in to make the call I need. How might I make the required call?

Comment: what you mean by this `retrieve a status for each item shown`. can you add the code where is it displayed?

Comment: My second API call is to retrieve a simple on/off indicator when supplied a key from each item from the data loaded in the first call.

Answer (score 2):

You can use observables in the results of your queries and subscribe components to those observables.

```js
// within service that colects documents from firestore
 
import { Injectable                    } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject               } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { AngularFirestore,
         AngularFirestoreCollection,
         AngularFirestoreDocument      } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class SomeService {

something_retrieved$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

 getSomething = () => {
    const collection = this._fireStore.collection('some_key');
    const collection_data = prod_coll.valueChanges();
    collection_data.map( data => this.something_retrieved$.next(data) ).subscribe((query) => {});
  };
 
 }
```

```js
// within some component

import { Component     } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeService   } from '@services/some.service';

@Component({
  selector    : 'app-element',
  templateUrl : './element.component.html',
  styleUrls   : [ './element.component.scss' ]
})
export class SomeComponent {

  constructor( private _service: SomeService ) {
    _service.something_retrieved.subscribe( retrieved => this.doSomething() )
  }

  doSomething = () => ... your secondary action
 }
```